# I want to add h1 tags in magento

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0

I just change to default theme, in my site www.fashionbelow.com, My SEO company wants me to put in the h1 tags to help with the Search engine rankings. Where can I put these in? Can I put them in using the ADMIN panel or do I have to put them into the actual code?

Thank you so much for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you please tell me Where you want that h1 tag

Comment: Thank you for answer, yes i did it now. Than you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly you want insert h1 tags? Way depend from place. For example: if this text in template code and u need change it in future you can insert CMS block in your theme and insert h1 inside CMS block in admin.

Comment: Thank you for answer, yes i did it now. Than you very much.